# Conditional expectation of a Markov-chain - can the conditioning Sigma-algebra be changed?

Tags: markov-chains, conditional-expectation

Let $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}_0}$ be a Markov-chain and $(\mathfrak{F}_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}_0}$ the induced filtration $\mathfrak{F}_n := \sigma(X_0, \dots, X_n)$. Is then $\mathbb{E}[X_n|\mathfrak{F}_{n-1}] = \mathbb{E}[X_n|\sigma(X_{n-1})]$?

What I mean is, when I actually try to figure out how a certain conditioned expectation of a random variable maps $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$, and the random variable and the $\sigma$-algebra in question happen to meet the above requirements, is it then sufficient, if

$\mathbb{E}[X_n, B] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X_n|\mathfrak{F}_{n-1}]X_n, B] \forall B \in \sigma(X_{n-1})$ (instead of ... $\forall B \in \mathfrak{F}_{n-1}$)?

Comment: Please explain your approach to the problem.

Comment: I hope this edit suffices to make the question clearer?

Comment: This stems from the **definition** of a real valued Markov chain when one adds the condition that every $X_n$ is integrable.

Comment: You mean: if $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a real-valued MC *and* every $X_n$ is integrable, then the conditioning $\sigma$-field can be changed?